# How to get all ids inside form when clicked on input type file

Tags: jquery

Hello i build a form to upload more document for customer there is a requirement to select files before add more document rows when anyone upload not supported format of file then i have a div where i show error

```
<div id="error_filename_" class="error"></div>
```

when customer repeat the upload process then i empty the text,first time my code work fine,this is my code

```
$("[id^='filename']").click(function(){
  var filenameids= $(this).attr('id');
  alert(filenameids);
  var incids=filenameids.replace("filename","");
  $("#error_filename_"+incids).text('');
 });
```

i empty the text of div to allow add more button to add doc row.but when i moved to second row and upload unsupported file then error message show but when i repeat uploading document div text not empty so i cant add add more button.so please tell me how to empty div text for each click and how to get id of that input type file.
js fiddle is

```
https://jsfiddle.net/fzmbw1vg/
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle, it is hard to understand what you ask.

Comment: i want to get all input ids of file  when clicked.

Comment: [Your code](https://jsfiddle.net/fzmbw1vg/1/) empties the error message for the row you click. What actually you want to achieve?

Comment: i want each id of input type file on click event

Comment: Do you need each id in array, or you just want to empty all error messages? If you want to empty all error messages select them this way `$("[id^=error_filename_]").text('')`.

Comment: not able to remove text this way.

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector from

```
$("[id^='filename']").click(function(){
```

to

```
$(".valid").click(function() {
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzmbw1vg/2/)

If you want to get all the ids then iterate through on the inputs and collect the ids into an array like in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzmbw1vg/3/)

```
$(".valid").click(function() {
  var ids = [];
  $('input[type="file"]').each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  alert(ids);
});
```

Comment: i already increment my id based on that id i fount text so delete text onclick event i want file id